# Scala Json Schema

Tags: scala, runtime, jsonschema

I tried to get json schema for different types using this library.
https://index.scala-lang.org/andyglow/scala-jsonschema/scala-jsonschema/0.7.6?target=_2.13

```
case class Pizza(a:Int, b:String)
val stringSchema: json.Schema[Pizza] = Json.schema[Pizza]
```

But I want to skip/hide some unsupported or not required fields.

```
case class Pizza(a:Int, b:String c:ZonedDateTime)//want to skip field c
```

Is there any way to do this? Or any other library we can achieve the same.

Comment: Where does `T` comes from? Can you share more context?

Comment: I got ans for my initial question which is 'no'. We not able to create Json Schema in run time using this library. so changed complete question as per requirement. please check.

Comment: It could have been useful for future readers to keep your original question and provide an answer. Then opening a new question.